# UIScrollView doesn't work well on screen rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview

I have added my UIScrollView and It has multiple subviews.The height of subviews are dynamic and When I get my data and set it ,The height would change and I have that extra added height inside a variable.I use that variable to add that extra height to contentsize of UIScrollView and It's working fine until I roate the screen which then the UIScrollView does this :

[image]

as you can see , The yellow uiView doesn't show completely and UIScrollView doesn't cover it at all.

What's the problem ?

Comment: Can you show how it should be? Is the yellow view a subview of scroll view, or is it a sibling? What should the scroll view cover?

Comment: @Losiowaty the yellow view is a subview of scroll view and the height is 200px . As you can see scrollView has just coverd a little bit of it

Comment: Well, I cant get the issue here. Can't you scroll the view, so that the yellow view is visible? Once again, a sketch of what you expected would be nice.

Comment: @Losiowaty , that's exactly the problem . I can't scroll the view more than that .

Comment: Oh, ok. Can you show some code, responsible for the `contentSize` calculations?